# JavaScript validation with alternative numeric and alphabetic digits

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript validation; it will contain only 6 digits but the new thing is that it will like this - `A1A1A1` it always start with alphabetic and then numeric and again it means alternative with alphabetic and numeric number with only six digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for javascript validation. It is very compact and effective. In your case you can try using :

/([A-Za-z]\d){3}/

This means : 
[A-Za-z] checks if the character is an alphabet.
\d checks for a digit.
When I am putting the stuff in parenthesis, followed by {3}, it checks for the recurrence of the (...)group thrice.

So in a set of 6 characters, you check thrice for a set of one alphabet, one digit occurrence.

Now you dont want uppercase, then use
[a-z] instead of [A-Za-z] in the regular expressions.

You can see an example here :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter the text you want to validate</p>

<input id="i01"></input>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    text = document.getElementById("i01").value; 
       alert(/^([A-Za-z]\d){3}$/.test(text));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i try this q1q1q1q1 or q1q1q1q then it also return true it`s wrong but i want to only for six digits after it should be return false

Comment: I have edited the code for you. Just check and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific about what you define as digits and/or letters...

If you want a string of total length 6 that follows the pattern:

`LDLDLD`

where `L` is a letter from `a-z` uppercase and `D` is a digit from `0` to `9` you could use regex inside Javascript to do something like this:

`^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$`

Comment: If the letters and numbers must be the same 3 times, you might want to use `^([A-Z][0-9]){3}$` instead

Comment: I don't think this guarantees they will be the same three times, I think your expression is equivalent to the one in the answer

Comment: It will match expressions like A2B4X4 but not A1A1a1... I believe that the first alternative is what he wanted